# GaugeField progress forward and rewind when playing audio?

Tags: blackberry

I'm developing a player Application which plays audio for some fixed time. I need to use Gaugefield such that it should fast-forward and rewind the Audio that is currently Playing.

I am able to get the time from the player and displaying on the screen. I need to update the time when the progress of Gaugefield is increased or decreased and at the same time I need to stream the player according to the level of the Gaugefield.

I used the sample code below but it is not working.

```
Player.stop(); 
Player.setMediaTime(); 
Player.start();
```

I am working on 6.0 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing a [PlayerListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/javax/microedition/media/PlayerListener.html)? If you implement PlayerListener, then you can use the playerUpdate() method to update your GaugeField.